# Comment traduire « learning from others » / « to learn from others » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

J'ai récemment écrit dans une rédaction:

> J'aime apprendre des autres.

Ma prof l'a encerclé, disant « reformuler ».

Franchement je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi ça ne marche pas. L'anglais est ma première langue donc peut-être j'essaie de traduire directement de l'anglais.

Ce que je voulais dire était (dans le contexte de l'éducation):

> I like learning from other people.

La seule autre traduction qui me parait possible est:

> J'aime apprendre des autres gens.

ou bien

> J'aime apprendre des autres personnes.

Comment: La tournure n‘est pas inexacte, [TLFI, I A B Rem 3)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apprendre). Cela dit, l’on apprend en général *quelque chose* de quelqu’un. Je pense que c’est ce que te suggère ta [professoresse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/professoresse). Plutôt que de traduire ta pensée de l’anglais, essaie de voir ce que tu veux exprimer, puis de le dire en français ; car si tu me demandes de traduire ta phrase, je la traduirais comme toi ; mais cela resterai une traduction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Apprendre des autres** se dit en français, est tout à fait correct et n'est pas ressenti comme une traduction.

Quelques exemples :

- [Extrait](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Q16kBGqEX50C&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22apprendre%20des%20autres%22&source=bl&ots=IPhSdpqsmm&sig=GEMNMyHhtoNu_dHOxzUsPd0BIzo&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=e7aoUsDrB4eZ0QX_zYHgCQ&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22apprendre%20des%20autres%22&f=false) d'[un livre](http://www.editions-harmattan.fr/index.asp?navig=catalogue&obj=livre&no=28364) paru en 2009 :

> Il s'agit d'apprendre ensemble, d'apprendre des autres, d'apprendre
>   aux autres dans un processus d'interaction.

- Une revue en formation des adultes a fait paraître [un numéro](http://www.education-permanente.fr/public/articles/articles.php?id_revue=151&id_article=225#resume225) qui s'intitulait *Apprendre des autres*.
- Un [article de journal](http://www.leparisien.fr/abo-seine-et-marne-sud/apprendre-des-autres-et-leur-communiquer-son-savoir-01-07-2009-565624.php) : *Apprendre des autres et leur communiquer son savoir*.
- [Une phrase](http://www.unige.ch/fapse/life/textes/Meirieu_A2001_02.html) souvent citée de [Philippe Meirieu](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Meirieu) (chercheur et écrivain français spécialiste des sciences de l'éducation) :

> apprendre des autres est nécessaire parce que nous ne pouvons pas
>   recréer le monde chacun à notre tour...

Ceci dit tu pourrais essayer de jouer sur « les autres » et de voir si « j'aime apprendre **d'autrui** » plaît plus à ta professeure.

Comment: Bonne suggestion suggestion supplémentaire avec autrui, Je n'y aurais pas pensé.