# Que signifie « chacun à notre tour » ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Issu d'une citation dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8173/1995) de Laure :

> L’acte d’apprendre est, en effet, la capacité à tenir ensemble ces deux exigences. Car apprendre, nul ne peut le faire à notre place.. et apprendre des autres est nécessaire parce que nous ne pouvons pas recréer le monde **chacun à notre tour** : ce qui nous caractérise comme être humain, c’est ce rapport à l’héritage.

Comment expliquer « chacun à notre tour » ? Je suppose que ça veut dire « … apprendre des autres est nécessaire car chacun de nous ne peut pas recréer le monde, au tour de chacun de nous … » ?

**Supplément daté le 29 janvier 2014 :**

Quels sont les points communs et les différences entre « chacun notre tour »  et « chacun à notre tour » ? Quand employer l'un en dehors de l'autre ?

Comment: Ça veut dire [à tour de rôle](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_tour_de_r%C3%B4le).

Comment: Si le *chacun notre tour* te perturbe, le sens de la phrase peut se simplifier par : *nous ne pouvons pas **tous** recréer le monde*.

Comment: @Laure ça, c'est une réponse, pas un commentaire.

Comment: @Shikiryu: Oui, bien sûr, mais c'est une façon de faire comprendre qu'on peut facilement trouver la réponse sans avoir à beaucoup chercher.

Answer (score 3):

L'expression *chacun à notre tour* (équivalent à *chacun son tour*, [*à tour de rôle*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_tour_de_r%C3%B4le)) est plus souvent exprimé par *chacun notre tour* (sans le à). Elle signifie généralement que chaque personne va effectuer une action par alternance.

> Ils vont lancer les dés chacun son tour

… signifie que le joueur 1 lance les dés, puis après le joueur 2, puis

Dans votre citation, l'expression signifie que nous ne pouvons pas tous recréer le monde, même si quelqu'un l'a déjà fait auparavant.

Comment: Chacun *leur* tour, non… ?

Comment: Oui, à mon avis, ça vient d'un problème de traduction de la citation originale. Je vais le noter.

Answer (score 1):

« Chacun son tour » ou « chacun à son tour » (accordé avec le sujet lorsqu'il y en a un, et cela devient alors « leur tour » ou « notre tour » ou « votre tour ») a le même sens que « à tour de rôle » ou « l'un après l'autre », c'est à dire que lorsque l'un des participants termine l'action, le suivant la commence.

Dans le contexte donné l'action est « recréer le monde ». En d'autres termes « il n'est pas concevable que chacun crée encore et encore des connaissances à partir de rien, sans tenir compte de celles apportées par le précédent ».